# Will Thermaltake Muse R-Duo Raid reset lose data?

Tags: external-hard-drive, raid, raid-1, chassis

I have a Thermaltake Muse R-Duo Raid chassis with two drives installed and DIP switches set to Raid-1. However, only the left lights are lighting up and I have data on the drive. I'm guessing it is because I never set it up correctly.

http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/Product.aspx?C=1290&ID=1661

Manual states: `WARNING: Changing the HDD mode deletes data stored on your hard disk drive(s).`

Manual states: `Press the Reset button (x) and continue pressing it for about 5 seconds
while turning on the device using the Power switch (x). Your device has
now been set to the new HDD mode.`

Would factory default be Raid-1, or must you reset it when first installing drives? Would I lose all the data on the left drive if I did the reset as described above? I have no easy way to back up the data as it is my DirecTV external drive for DVR.